# Phonegap / Cordova css not working correctly

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

I have a problem when transferring my app to phonegap. when I look the site in browser it appears normal, buttons are in line with text (even when i resize it to the size of the tablet im using), BUT when i try it on phonegap its messed up.

How it looks like (stackoverflow doesnt allow me upload images, my rep not 10)
http://postimg.org/image/k49v615zz/

How it should look like
http://postimg.org/image/3t6g1a01p/

both screenshots are taken in the browser, but the first one has

```
display: inline-flex !important;
```

unticked, as u can see on the prntscr. Anyone had similar problem,any idea how to fix this?

index.js part with appending problematic buttons

```
if(value.countable==true){
$detailList.append("
    <div  id='countable'>
        <span>"+value.detailName+"</span>
        <div data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal' data-mini='true'>
            <button class='button detailRow qtyminus' id='minus' data-inline='true'>-</button>
            <input type='number' class='qty' min='0' inputmode='numeric' pattern='[0-9]*' name=detail."+value.detailId+" id="+value.detailId+" value="+ ((value.quantity == null)? + " 0": value.quantity) +" />
            <button class='button detailRow qtyplus' id='plus' data-inline='true'>+</button>
    </div>").trigger("create");
            }
```

CSS

```
#countable {
    width:100%;
}

#countable span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19em;
}

#countable div {
    display:inline-block;
}
.qty {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width: 9em;
    height: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}
input.qtyplus { 
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width:2em; 
    height:2em;
}

input.qtyminus { 
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width:2em; 
    height:2em;
}

.workerRow, .categoryRow, .taskRow {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use % in elements.

CSS

```
#countable span {
display: inline-block;
width: 60%;
}

.qty {
position:relative;
float:right;
width: 30%;
height: 3em;
text-align: center;
}

input.qtyplus { 
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width:5%; 
    height:2em;
}

input.qtyminus { 
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width:5%; 
    height:2em;
}
```

Total elements space 100% of width

But try use this in your project, i used this to all my projects, is simple and efficient

CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    outline: none; 
}

.row:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }

.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666666666667%;
}

.col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
}

.col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666666666667%;
}

.col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33333333333333%;
}

.col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666666666667%;
}

.col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
}

.col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333333333%;
}

.col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666666666667%;
}

.col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

How to use, is simple. Max size columns are 12.

E.g

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

3 columns with size 4 * 3 = 12

To your problem use this

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6"></div>
   <div class="col-md-1"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

The grid system are perfect, use this! (small demo http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/Bk2gB/1/)

Comment: Add 4 divs (like columns), put in elements this sizes:

element-1 : 60%
element-2 : 5%;
element-3 : 30%;
element-4 : 5%;

all elements must be float:left, inside elements put your elements one by one

Comment: like this? 
<div class='row'><div class='col-md-6'>"+value.detailName+"</div><div class='col-md-1'><button id='minus'>-</button></div><div class='col-md-4'><input type='number'  min='0' inputmode='numeric' pattern='[0-9]*' name=detail."+value.detailId+" id="+value.detailId+" value="+ ((value.quantity == null)? + " 0": value.quantity) +" /></div><div class='col-md-1'><button id='plus'>+</button></div></div>"

Comment: Yep, if size are not good, try other combinations. like (4 - 2 - 4 - 2)

Comment: You put grid system on css?
Your project have bootstrap?

Comment: yea here's jsfiddle with the relevant code
P.s. no bootstrap, i forgot to put that grid system, but when i put it, it looks even weirder http://postimg.org/image/dh1u07uhv/

Comment: When i removed 
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px; from your code, it worked like a charm :) THANKS

Comment: Ohhhhhh man, sorry i forgot this
 *, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
}

WARNING: if you put this in your code, all elements (with padding) change size... try this to see how it works

http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/Bk2gB/1/